# Read private data of smart contracts from Blockchain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, security, private

Is there any way to read smart contracts private or internal data from Blockchain?
The smart contract data is on Blockchain so probably the data can be read from servers. Is data encrypted on Blockchain?

I want to store sensitive data in my smart contract but I just want to know is this normal or I should store contract sensitive data on some other trusted sources?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All data can be seen by external parties. The solution to this is to send the data encrypted to the smart contract, such that to retrieve it, your private key would be required.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add a way to retrieve `private` data?